# What does mkdir -p create as the parent directory?

Tags: windows, unix, cmd, mkdir

I read from http://www.techonthenet.com/unix/basic/mkdir.php that the mkdir command "creates a single directories or multiple directories." and that -p "If the parent directories don't exist, this command creates them". I tried this command in cmd(window operating system) and saw that with -p and without -p, the command just created a file with a file name. How do you see the effect of "If parent directories don't exist creates them." I am assuming C:\Users\chris> is the parent directory when i run the command(therefore the parent directory exists). Is there a way of seeing the effect of -p?

Comment: I dont think this is off topic, isn't this in operating system section?

Comment: Firstly, this is not programming related so it should go to [su]. Secondly, why are you testing a Unix command in Windows?

Comment: i dont have a unix installed. i put this question on there

Comment: It worked as it should. Isn't this a common operating system command then?

Comment: Windows and Unix both have commands called "mkdir" that do roughly the same thing but they're not the same commands. Most importantly, the Windows version doesn't have the -p flag.

Comment: oh. is there a way of installing a unix operating system in a window environment(do you recommend a way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try help.

```
C:\Users\User>mkdir/?
Creates a directory.

MKDIR [drive:]path
MD [drive:]path

If Command Extensions are enabled MKDIR changes as follows:

MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

**Installing Unix**

Unix Services for Windows are either a download from MS website or installed via Control Panel - Programs and Features - Windows Features. Which depends on version and edition of your Windows.